# Run MATLAB script in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm looking for a way to execute MATLAB code in a python file without using MATLAB. This is my MATLAB code:

```
count = 0
for image_name in os.listdir(directory_segmentation):
    if count < n_displays:
        segmented_image = cv2.imread(directory_segmentation + "/" + image_name)

        segmented = Image.open(directory_segmentation + "/" + image_name)
        original = Image.open(directory_originals + "/" + image_name)

        font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)

        d1 = ImageDraw.Draw(segmented)
        masked = self.create_mask_plaque(segmented_image, color_plaque)
        maxlevel = 3
        **v = self.waveletdescr(masked, maxlevel)**
        print(v)

    count += 1
```

And the function that it's between ** ** it's coded in MATLAB. So I need to give some parameters to it and get back a vector. Is it possible? Thank you!!
PD. The structure of the MATLAB script looks like this:

```
function v = waveletdescr(im,maxlevel) ;
im = rgb2gray(im)
im = double(im);
[m,n] = size(im);
npix = m*n;

....

v = zeros( 3*maxlevel+1, 1 ); % the descriptors
end
  
v(end) = sum(sum( im.^2 )) / npix; 

function imf = filterh(im,l)
  d = size(im(end-1:-1:end-l,:))
  imf = 0.5*[im; im(end-1:-1:end-l,:)];
  imf = imf(1:end-l,:) + imf(l+1:end,:);

function imf = filterg(im,l)
  imf = 0.5*[im; im(end-1:-1:end-l,:)];
  imf = imf(l+1:end,:) - imf(1:end-l,:);
```

Comment: Why don't you just write the MATLAB function in Python?

Comment: I try it but the output it's not the same so I think I'm doing something wrong but I can't find the error:(

Comment: The easiest option is probably to keep trying to translate your MATLAB function into Python. If you really get stuck and can't produce the same results in each, post on this site with the appropriate language tag to see if someone can find where your code is going wrong.